# "bundle install" fails when setting :git path in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, prawn

I want to update one of my gems from the master source branch instead of from a gem repo. So I put this in my Gemfile:

```
gem "prawn", :git => "https://github.com/sandal/prawn.git"
```

However, now when I run:

```
bundle install
```

or:

```
bundle update
```

I get:

```
Updating https://github.com/sandal/prawn.git
syntax error on line 42, col 0: `end'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:137:in `load': undefined method `path' for #<String:0x101aa83c0> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:480:in `from_yaml'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler.rb:238:in `load_gemspec'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler.rb:235:in `chdir'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler.rb:235:in `load_gemspec'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/source.rb:353:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/source.rb:352:in `each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/source.rb:352:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/source.rb:570:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/source.rb:385:in `local_specs'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/source.rb:555:in `specs'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/definition.rb:356:in `converge_locked_specs'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/definition.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/definition.rb:345:in `converge_locked_specs'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/definition.rb:143:in `resolve'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/definition.rb:85:in `resolve_remotely!'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.20/bin/bundle:13
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@myapp/bin/bundle:19
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: could you try it with `git://github.com/sandal/prawn.git`

Comment: It results in the same problem.

Comment: ok just tried to include prawn this way in one of my projects, and it works fine with ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2 bundler 1.0.15 and 1.0.20. `bundle install` works fine if you remove the prawn line from your gemfile?

Comment: gonna install ree, and try with that, just a mom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of rubygems I was using. Once I upgraded to version 1.8.15, this worked appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

try pulling it in manually using git git://github.com/sandal/prawn.git then include it in your bundler then bundle install alrytz